# The acction hook stop working if i move it from plugin file to theme's functions.php file

Tags: hooks, actions, buddypress

A **bp_includes** is buddypress action and hooked on **plugins_loaded**

```
function remove_bp_docs() {
    global $wpdb;

    $current_user = get_current_user_id();

    //We are selecting member type before buddypress load so bp_get_member_type won't work neither wp_get_object_terms
    $query = "SELECT t.slug FROM {$wpdb->terms} AS t INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} AS tt ON tt.term_id = t.term_id INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} AS tr ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id WHERE tt.taxonomy = 'bp_member_type' AND tr.object_id = $current_user";

    $member_type = $wpdb->get_var( $query );

    if ( ! empty($member_type ) && 'client' == $member_type ) {
        remove_action( 'bp_include', 'bp_docs_init' );
    }

}
add_action( 'bp_include', 'remove_bp_docs', 9 );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about what you've written:

> The acction hook stop working if i move it from plugin file to theme's
>   functions.php file

And:

> `bp_includes` is buddypress action and hooked on `plugins_loaded`

The problem is that the code stops working when you move the code to `functions.php`, which is a ***theme*** file. The theme loads after plugins load and hence after `plugins_loaded`. Take a look at the hook sequence for a typical page load: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_a_Typical_Request

In fact, the first hook available to a theme is `after_setup_theme`.

It sounds like your code has to be in a plugin or mu-plugin.

Comment: Thanks!! I really appreciate your answer. okay so you mean that the **functions.php** file has been included on `after_setup_theme` right?

Comment: No. I didn't say that nor did I mean that. The file is not included on a hook at all. I am just pointing out the first hook that a theme has available and pointing out the fact that it is after the one you need has already fired.

Comment: I got my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20753876/checking-for-buddypress-from-a-theme. It means the same though. :)